# How to import media/stagefright/* classes in Android native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, stagefright

I'm trying to compile some [NDK code](https://github.com/ivygroup/miracast-sink) (via *ndk-build* ), but I get this error :

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: wfd_jni <= SinkPlayer.cpp
In file included from jni/SinkPlayer.cpp:4:0:
jni/SinkPlayer.h:5:48: fatal error: media/stagefright/foundation/ABase.h: No such file or directory
 #include <media/stagefright/foundation/ABase.h>
```

I tried importing the same project in Android Studio, but it still doesn't find the *media/** imports (it shows those lines in *red* )

Most likely I have to include that package in my *build path* somewhere, but this is my first time working with the NDK and I cannot figure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stagefright is not park of the public API, so is not included in the NDK. It is internal to the media framework on Android.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But there must be a way to add it somehow so I can run that sample, right? Or else why would the author have written it in the example ?

Comment: What sample are you looking at?

Comment: Look at my question, the "NDK Code" word is actually a link

Comment: The link is to a project which is to be added to a custom platform build (custom ROM), not a for a 3rd party app built against the NDK.